# How to reference Android holo resources from code?

Tags: android

How do I reference Android holo resources within Java code? Like the blue colors or drawables? It seams these are not available in android.R...

Comment: What is your target SDK of the project? It should work like this  `android.R.color.holo_blue_bright`

Comment: For me, `android.R.drawable` didn't show up in Android Studio (2.0) auto complete when starting to type that.. but once I got this far: `android.R.` .. then the autocomplete showed up for `.drawable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android contains a number of standard resources, such as styles, themes, and layouts. To access these resource, qualify your resource reference with the android package name (see original source [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#PlatformResources)).

Here is an exemple for image :

> ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
>   imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

If the import android.R cannot be found, you should check your project properties and set the right platform sdk. From Eclipse, right click on project > properties > android and choose the corresponding "project build target".

Answer (score 0):

You can also just "copy" the style and modify the parts you don't like, i.e.:

```
<style name="StyledIndicators" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>  
</style>
```

[more examples](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html)